# PHP, Don't submit if there is errors

Tags: php

Below is my PHP code, currently, it shows all errors and etc, but if one of them are correct it will submit the form, How could I change my code so that if 1 is not correct is does not submit

```
<?php
$cusMsg = "";
$fNameMsg = "";

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {  
    $id = $_POST["custid"];

    if(empty($id)) {
        $cusMsg = '<span class="error"> Field was left empty</span>';
    } else if(!is_numeric($id)) {
        $cusMsg = '<span class="error"> Customer ID must be numeric</span>';
    } else if(strlen($id) != 6) {
        $cusMsg = '<span class="error"> Customer ID must be 6 digits long</span>';
    } else {
        return true;
    }

}

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {  
    $fName = $_POST["customerfname"];
    $pattern = "/^[a-zA-Z-]+$/";

    if(empty($fName)) {
        $fNameMsg = '<span class="error"> Field was left empty</span>';
    } else if(!preg_match($pattern, $fName)) {
        $fNameMsg = '<span class="error"> First name must only containt letters and hyphens</span>';
    } else if(strlen($fName) > 20) {
        $fNameMsg = '<span class="error"> First name must not be longer than 20 characters</span>';
    } else {
        return true;
    }

}

}
?>
```

Comment: go read in the manual what `return` does

Comment: @Dagon Thank you, :) read up on it carefully, Know what it does got rid of those statements on all of them, then put all code into 1 issest($_POST["submit"]) and it worked :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of else in the last use else if and pass this

```
else if(!empty($fName) && preg_match($pattern, $fName) && strlen($fName) < 20){
return true;
}
```

It just checks all your condition using AND operator and returns true only if all conditions are met

Answer (score 1):

You could set a flag variable $submit to false by default.

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {  

   $submit = false; // Add this

   $id = $_POST["custid"];

   if (empty($id)) {

       $cusMsg = '<span class="error"> Field was left empty</span>';

   } else if (!is_numeric($id)) {

       $cusMsg = '<span class="error"> Customer ID must be numeric</span>';

   } else if(strlen($id) != 6) {

        $cusMsg = '<span class="error"> Customer ID must be 6 digits long</span>';

   } else {

      $submit = true;
   }

  // Now check the value of $submit and write your code accordingly.

  if ($submit) {
     // Write your submit action
  } else {
     // Other action
  }

}
```